# TypeScript Recursive function returns undefined

Tags: typescript, recursion, tree

I have an array of Objects with the following structure:

```
{
  Name: "Automotive"
  RefCategory: 1,
  ChildCategories:[{
     Name: "Car"
     RefCategory: 2,
     ChildCategories: []
  },{
     Name: "Motorcycle"
     RefCategory: 3,
     ChildCategories: []
  }]
}
```

I wrote a function to find a Category Node given its Ref:

```
navigateToNode(node: any, RefCategoryToFind: number): any {

    if (node.RefCategory == RefCategoryToFind)
        return node;

    node.ChildCategories.forEach(value => {
        if (value.RefCategory == RefCategoryToFind)
            return value;
        else {
            if (value.ChildCategories.length !== 0)
                return this.navigateToNode(value, RefCategoryToFind);                
        }
    });
}
```

This function returns null when I call

```
let x = this.navigateToNode(this.activeCategories[0], 2);
```

I can see it hits the `return value;` and thus found the right node, but returns undefined.

Comment: The callback to `forEach` returns something, but that does **not** mean that `navigateToNode` does.

Comment: But should it not exit when it hits the return? How do I adapt it to work?

Comment: The *callback* exits. The outer function is separate. Why not use a regular for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your callback is returning a value, but the wrapping function does not return anything. Try saving the return value when it is found and return it:

```
navigateToNode(node: any, RefCategoryToFind: number): any {

    if (node.RefCategory == RefCategoryToFind)
        return node;

    var result;

    node.ChildCategories.forEach(value => {
        if (value.RefCategory == RefCategoryToFind) {
            result = value;
            return value;
        } else {
            if (value.ChildCategories.length !== 0)
                return this.navigateToNode(value, RefCategoryToFind);                
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hello. I have just encountered a similar situation. my function works `function parentUnit(element) {
    var unit = element.parentElement;
    if (unit != null) {
        if (!unit.classList.contains("unit")) {
            unit = parentUnit(unit);
        }
    }
    return unit;
}` but I am curious why should the wrapping function return something if the IF statement already has (I had `return unit;` inside `if(unit.classList.contains("unit")` and it returned undefined.

Comment: @iJassar your situation is different. Note that there is a ```value => {...}``` in the code above, which is an arrow function. The return statement in the question was present inside this inner, arrow function, but the wrapper function did not have a return. In your situation there is a single Javascript function, which takes an input parameter called element, puts its parentElement into unit, and, if unit does not have a unit class, then unit is overriden by the recursive call for parentUnit. At the end of the function unit is returned.

Comment: @iJassar now, your function is doing the following in plain words: while the element does not have a unit class, go up in the hierarchy. Now, if the element you pass to this function does not have that class, nor any of its ancestors in the hierarchy, then this function will go up in the hierarchy to parent, grandparent, etc. until there is no more defined parent. Then, this undefined value is returned to the caller, then to the caller of the caller, etc. until it reaches the initial call which will, on its turn also return undefined.

Comment: @iJassar so the bug in your case is that while your code assumes that the element passed to the function or any of its ancestors has the unit class, so you will need to look into the HTML structure involved.

Comment: Thank you, Lajos! The thing is that the code I have shared **actually works**. But if I have `return unit;` inside of the if statement, it doesn't, which doesn't make sense because the IF statement is not a function inside of the function, so what's the reason for this behavior?

Comment: @iJassar the reason is that none of the ancestors of the tag you passed to the function has the unit class, hence the parentUnit function is recursively called again and again, always passing the parentElement as element to the function called, until it reaches a state where the parentElement is null. Then that's returned to the caller, then the caller returns it to the caller's caller and so on. This is the reason of the undefined. If this is still unclear, then please ask a separate question and send me a link to it in the comment section. The answer features allow me to better explain this.